# Showing the estimator is consistent

Tags: probability

Follow up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4211968/deriving-the-mle-of-theta-for-f-xx-alpha-theta-frac1-alpha-1-thet).

I am trying to show that the estimator is *mean consistent* with $\theta$ i.e. $MSE(\hat{\theta})=0$.

It is known that $Var(X)=\alpha\theta^2$ and $E(X)=\alpha\theta$

We know that $MSE(\hat{\theta})=Var(\hat{\theta})+Bias(\hat{\theta})$

Bias is easy to show to be $0$:

Bias$ = E(\hat{\theta})-\theta$

$E(\hat{\theta}) = E\left(\frac{\sum x_i}{n\alpha}\right) = \frac{\sum E(x_i)}{n\alpha}=\frac{n \alpha\theta}{n \alpha}=\theta$

However I am struggling to show that the variance is equal to $0$:

$Var(\hat{\theta})=Var\left(\frac{\sum x_i}{n\alpha}\right)=\frac{1}{(n\alpha)^2}Var(\sum x_i)=\frac{1}{(n\alpha)^2}\left(E\left(\left(\sum x_i\right)^2\right)-E(\sum x_i)^2\right)$

I know that $E(\sum x_i)^2=(n\alpha\theta)^2$ but not sure what's the first expression equal to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer:

The distribution is a Gamma with mean $\mu=\alpha\theta$

Thus

$$\theta=\frac{\mu}{\alpha}$$

Using SLLN (Strong Law of Large Numbers) we have that

$$\frac{\Sigma_i X_i}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mu$$

thus

$$\frac{\Sigma_i X_i}{\alpha n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\frac{\mu}{\alpha}=\theta$$

That is

$$\hat{\theta}_{ML}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\theta$$

Strong convergence implies Weak Convergence

---

If you want to calculate, as you tried, $L^2$ convergence (which also implies weak convergence), first note that $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased thus you only have to evaluate the limit of its variance.

Now note that, if $X\sim \text{Gamma}[\alpha;\theta]$ then

$$\Sigma_i X_i\sim \text{Gamma}[n\alpha;\theta]$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}_{ML}]=\frac{n\alpha\theta^2}{n^2\alpha^2}=\frac{\theta^2}{n\alpha}$$

and obviously

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\theta^2}{n\alpha}=0$$

Comment: But how do you justify using the Strong Law if OP said that $X_i$ are **not** i.i.d.? It puzzles me why he accepted your answer as the best answer while explicitly commenting that his sample is not i.i.d., and at the same time you used i.i.d. both to invoke LLN in the first part and then to find $\mathbb{V}(\hat \theta_{ML}) = \frac{\theta^2}{n\alpha}$ in the 2nd part. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean $MSE(\hat \theta) \rightarrow 0$? Then the part involving the variance is clearly $o_p(1)$, since $Var(\sum_i x_i) = nVar(x)$.

Comment: the variables aren't IID, so it can't be that $Var(\sum x_i)=nVar(x)$

Comment: But what is the structure then? How can this estimator be consistent if, e.g., all $x_i$ are perfectly correlated? For instance, if you have a sample with $N=1$, and you just repeat $x_i$ any number of times? Clearly the variance won't converge to zero, as long as $x_i$ is not degenerate.

Comment: @econbernardo: the OP wrote that this answer is related to another one (that you can see in its link) where the n rv's are iid because they are a random sample from a gamma distributed population

Comment: @tommik Yet, at the same time he commented on my answer that the variables **aren't** i.i.d. See his comment above.